# Only rendering Mapbox features once, when showing multiple world copies?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm working on this Mapbox map, and shows features using geojson/FeatureCollection ([basically something like this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/multiple-geometries/)).

If you zoom all the way out, the map will show multiple world copies (which I want), but it will also show each feature on ALL world copies (don't want this!). What should I do so that the mapbox only displays the features on ONE of the world copies?

The example linked above also has the same issue (as you can see in the image below).

[image]

### Sample code showcasing the issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add multiple geometries from one GeoJSON source</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2h1YmhhbW1laHJhIiwiYSI6ImNqempxZWNqeDBicnMzbnFpaTZ6amVmYjQifQ.US2y0mYyWtRABvxzfpBWrw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11',
center: [-121.403732, 40.492392],
zoom: 10
});
 
map.on('load', function () {
map.addSource('national-park', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': {
'type': 'FeatureCollection',
'features': [
{
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Polygon',
'coordinates': [
[
[-121.353637, 40.584978],
[-121.284551, 40.584758],
[-121.275349, 40.541646],
[-121.246768, 40.541017],
[-121.251343, 40.423383],
[-121.32687, 40.423768],
[-121.360619, 40.43479],
[-121.363694, 40.409124],
[-121.439713, 40.409197],
[-121.439711, 40.423791],
[-121.572133, 40.423548],
[-121.577415, 40.550766],
[-121.539486, 40.558107],
[-121.520284, 40.572459],
[-121.487219, 40.550822],
[-121.446951, 40.56319],
[-121.370644, 40.563267],
[-121.353637, 40.584978]
]
]
}
},
{
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Point',
'coordinates': [-121.415061, 40.506229]
}
},
{
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Point',
'coordinates': [-121.505184, 40.488084]
}
},
{
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Point',
'coordinates': [-121.354465, 40.488737]
}
}
]
}
});
 
map.addLayer({
'id': 'park-boundary',
'type': 'fill',
'source': 'national-park',
'paint': {
'fill-color': '#888888',
'fill-opacity': 0.4
},
'filter': ['==', '$type', 'Polygon']
});
 
map.addLayer({
'id': 'park-volcanoes',
'type': 'circle',
'source': 'national-park',
'paint': {
'circle-radius': 6,
'circle-color': '#B42222'
},
'filter': ['==', '$type', 'Point']
});
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think question should have been closed. It's perfectly clear, and focused on a single, very specific issue.

Comment: This question could be opened again if the code to reproduce the problem was shared

Comment: The issue is showing with the default behavior of mapbox, so don't think sample code is necessary. And the linked example above is to a minimal example showing this issue (which the screenshot is from). But just in case, I've added the same sample code to the question as well. But I do not agree with the closing of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Geographically, what you're asking for doesn't really make sense. Your point has the same location as the map tile underneath it, so to have the basemap display but not your point, on the basis of the user having effectively rotated the map is...weird.

Your best workaround would be to use a `Marker` rather than a symbol layer. Each Marker is a single DOM element so only ever displayed once.

Comment: I just refactored a lot of code away from using `Marker` since that has other limitations. :S